# How to change data in column based on condition on mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am displaying data on mat table from rest api, In which there is a column "changeType" which displaying data in numeric form. Here it displaying "4" for "Add", and "1" for "Update".
I want to display the proper word instead of number to make user more understandable. How can i achieve it?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="changeType">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Type </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.changeType}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: whats' the output for above code ?

Comment: @anantvikramSingh in change type column it is displaying "4" it means "4" is used for "Add" and "1" means for "Update". I just want to display "Add" instead of 4. and "Add" for 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a function that take in input element.changeType and return the real value:

in html :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="changeType">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Type </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{resolveEnum(element.changeType)}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

in .ts

```
resolveEnum(num: number) {
  if(num == 1) 
   return "Update"
 else if(.....)
  .....
}
```

Obviously this is only an example you can make resolveEnum function better with switch case etc..

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Drenai I made a batter solution, from the performance point of view.

I made a resolEnum **pipe** so:

Make the pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'resolveEnum'
})
export class ResolveEnum implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private utility: UtilityService) { }

    transform(value: number): string {
        return this.utility.resolveEnum(value);
    }
}
```

where utilityService is a service where there is resolveEnum function.

In html:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="changeType">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Type </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element | resolveEnum}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: @AshishMishra The right solution for this is to create an Enum.

Comment: @Tzimpo sure, in fact I use it with enum and switch case, not surprisingly it is called resolveEnum

Comment: @AshishMishra I'm very glad of this

Comment: @AshishMishra i wrote an answer with enum example