# replace name on mat-table Angular typescrypt

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Hi I am new to Angular and I've been searching for the last couple of days for a way to replace a string that comes from datasource for another to be displayed at the table row for example:

```
if (element.transaction == "R"){ element.transaction = "Received"} else{ element.transaction = "Paid"}
```

I really did search maybe my criteria was wrong but please do not give me a thumb down for not searching.

HTML

```
 <!-- transactions Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="transactions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Transactions </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ element.transactions }}
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

component.TS

````
export class ManualMovementsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  title = 'movement';

  movements: ManualMovements[] = [];

  movement: ManualMovements= {
    id: '',
    activ: true,
    name: '',
    code: '',
    transactions: '',
  };

displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'select',
    'name',
    'code',
    'transactions',
    'star',
  ];


 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ManualMovements>(
      this.movements
    );```
````

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this answer that is exactly what I was looking for:

```
 resolveEnum(str: string) {
if (str === 'E') {
  return 'Receive';
} else {
  return 'Pay';
}
```

}

This is the link where I found it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60798000/20479263

Thanks anyways